# Pyinstaller django static files not being used on Windows

Tags: django, pyinstaller

I'm using PyInstaller to try and make running of a Django project simple for a user.  It works perfectly on my Linux PC but when I try and create it on a Windows PC the static files are not loading and I cannot understand why.

I'm using the following `.spec` file to create the application.

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['manage.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\henry\\potential-waffle'],
             binaries=[("C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Redist/ucrt/DLLs/arm", '.')],
             datas=[('media','media'),('potential_waffle/static','static')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='webscraper',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='webscraper')
```

My static files are defined within `settings.py` as:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "potential_waffle/static"),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

And I'm picking up the static files for `runserver`:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The program works fine and does everything it should except the formatting of the browser and within terminal I have the following:

```
[08/Jun/2018 12:00:57] "GET /login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5438
[08/Jun/2018 12:00:57] "GET /static/agency/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[08/Jun/2018 12:00:57] "GET /static/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[08/Jun/2018 12:00:57] "GET /static/agency/css/agency.css HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[08/Jun/2018 12:00:57] "GET /static/toastr/toastr.min.css HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[08/Jun/2018 12:00:57] "GET /static/js/cookiechoices.js HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[08/Jun/2018 12:00:57] "GET /static/agency/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[08/Jun/2018 12:00:57] "GET /static/agency/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[08/Jun/2018 12:00:57] "GET /static/agency/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[08/Jun/2018 12:00:57] "GET /static/agency/js/contact_me.js HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[08/Jun/2018 12:00:57] "GET /static/agency/js/agency.min.js HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[08/Jun/2018 12:00:57] "GET /static/toastr/toastr.min.js HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[08/Jun/2018 12:00:57] "GET /login/?next=/static/agency/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 5490
[08/Jun/2018 12:00:57] "GET /login/?next=/static/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 5482
[08/Jun/2018 12:00:57] "GET /login/?next=/static/agency/css/agency.css HTTP/1.1" 200 5466
[08/Jun/2018 12:00:57] "GET /login/?next=/static/js/cookiechoices.js HTTP/1.1" 200 5464
[08/Jun/2018 12:00:57] "GET /login/?next=/static/toastr/toastr.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 5466
[08/Jun/2018 12:00:57] "GET /login/?next=/static/agency/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 5479
[08/Jun/2018 12:00:57] "GET /login/?next=/static/agency/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 5488
[08/Jun/2018 12:00:57] "GET /login/?next=/static/agency/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js HTTP/1.1" 200 5479
[08/Jun/2018 12:00:57] "GET /login/?next=/static/agency/js/contact_me.js HTTP/1.1" 200 5468
[08/Jun/2018 12:00:57] "GET /login/?next=/static/agency/js/agency.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 5468
[08/Jun/2018 12:00:57] "GET /login/?next=/static/toastr/toastr.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 5465
```

The files are in the `/static` folder (I've checked) but it seems to be redirecting them to a location where the files do not exist (even though we get a 200 response).

I am guessing there is something wrong with the .spec file for Windows but I've tried changing the slashes every which way to no avail.  I do get some warning messages during the build (which could be the issue) of the style:

`WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\henry\potential-waffle\env\scripts\python.exe`

Comment: For some reason they are behaving like a protected route. Do you have a minimal repo we can use to reproduce this?

Comment: I don't, but I can give you access to the application through github if that suits?

Comment: thanks, I've added your id

Comment: will do but I'm on a linux machine at the moment and will not be able to do this till this evening

Comment: I have checked on Windows and I can reproduce the issue. It seems to be a bug because the `staticfiles` class is not loaded at all. Also during the build there is a warning `WARNING: Hidden import "django.contrib.staticfiles.context_processors" not found!`, not sure if it indicates the same issue

Comment: See this https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2348